# How am I incorrectly solving this polar equations graph?

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

> Graph: $r = 1 + 2\cos(\theta)$

I set up a table of values and increment them by $π/2$:

$$\begin{array}
{|c|c|}\hline
\phantom{\_\_\_}\theta\phantom{\_\_\_} &  \phantom{\_\_\_}r\phantom{\_\_\_} \\ \hline
0      &  3 \\ \hline
\pi/2  &  1 \\ \hline
\pi    & -1 \\ \hline
3\pi/2 &  1 \\ \hline
2\pi   &  3 \\ \hline
5\pi/2 &  1 \\ \hline
3\pi   & -1 \\ \hline
7\pi/2 &  1 \\ \hline
4\pi   &  3 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

When I plot these points I get:

[image]

When I go about graphing I think of $\theta$ as direction, and $r$ as distance. So I point in a direction, and go a certain distance. Then to the next one and I connect the dots. But there seems to be more going on than just connecting the dots when I look at the actual graph on Desmos. How am I supposed to know it's going to loop inwards, go through the $y$-axis, and go back to $1$ on the $x$-axis?
Actual:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: you should try smaller increment.

Comment: "How am I suppose to know it's going to loop inwards?": from the fact that the function takes negative values.

Comment: When you draw polar graphs you also need to know when $r=0$ holds. the ones that you did not consider. For short for a polar system find the following before making its graph: 1) finding zeros (for both $\theta$ and $r$ if exist) 2) find all reflections 3) find values of $r$ by changing $\theta$ for well known degrees. 4) find out between 2 consecutive degrees how $r$ changes (decreasing or increasing) 5) with all these information start to draw your graph

Comment: It should be obvious to you that 1) computing every $\pi/2$ is too few and 2) computing on $4\pi$ is too much.

Comment: Also please learn to write tables in mathjax / latex.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What happens when 'r' is negative. I thought the rule was, when 'r' is negative then invert the theta and go the distance but reverse, so instead of on here, 3π/2 it will be π/2 and instead of -1 it's 1 for distance. Is that right?

Comment: @SaeidAli Just a little confused, when r = 0. Finding the zeros is simply setting the entire polar to 0. So sin(Θ) = -1/2....Θ = 7π/6, 11π/6.

Comment: A polar point is either a $r$ at the given $\theta$ or the $-r$ at $\theta+\pi$.

Comment: when $r=0$, then $\cos(\theta)=\frac{-1}{2}$. Then note that the duration of rotation (I forgot the name: it is the size of rotation you require that cause the repetition of total system) in your case is $2\pi$. So in the interval $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$ we have the two $\pi-\pi/3$ and $\pi+\pi/3$ where $\cos(\theta)=-1/2$.

Comment: Do not worry, at the beginning every one make mistake. With some practice you will be an expert.

Comment: @SaeidAli Is a -1 an indication for a loop? and also if and when possible it is forced to go through the origin? I understand how polar graphs are in this counter clockwise whirlpool and forces them to pull that way.

Comment: I do not get the point of your first question. But for the second the origin is just the point $r=0$ and what ever we have for $\theta$. So to go through the origin you only need to find all the angles which cause $r=0$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see that the polar curve loops inward is to graph $r$ versus $\theta$ on cartesian axes.  You see that $r$ becomes negative when $\cos\theta < -\frac{1}{2}$; that is on the interval $\left(\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I am able to graph it up until the graph turns red, then I get lost as to what to do. Because I am connecting the dots, but the dots instead of going in straight linear lines loop and curve, this confuses me. And not sure how to know when it will have this behavior or when it will just be connecting the dots.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to get a better picture of what the graph should look like, you should solve for ALL of the x intercepts (where theta equals 0 or pi) and y intercepts (where theta equals pi over two or three times pi over two).  Also, solving for where the radius equals zero is always helpful.

Also calculus students are generally taught the general equation for this type of equations (r = k + Lcos(Θ)).  When you see this form, you can use three general rules.  1) if k = L, then you will have a perfect cardioid 2) if k > L you will have something similar to a cardioid but closer to a circle 3) if k < L (like yours) then you will have a loop.
(This also applies to when the function is a sine function instead of cosine)